# django form styling with bootstrap4 problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, bootstrap-4

I got some problems styling a form in django with bootstrap. I tried some diffrent ways to get it to work but cant.

Any ideas how to style this form with bootstrap 4?

edited with the base.html code so you can see the imports.

at the moment with the code i have it looks like this.
[styling at the moment picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULRmu.png)

**edit_profile_page.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Edit Profile Page{% endblock %}
{% block content %}


{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% if user.id == profile.user.id %}
        <h1>Edit Profile Page</h1>
        <br/><br/>

        <div class="form-group">
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <button class="btn btn-info">Update Profile Page</button>
        </div>



    {% else %}

    You got no access here!
    {% endif %}

{% else %}

You got no access here!


{% endif %}


{% endblock %}
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm, PasswordChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from newsapp.models import Profile

class ProfilePageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('bio', 'profile_pic', 'website_url', 'facebook_url', 'twitter_url', 'instagram_url', 'pinterest_url')

        widgets = {
            'bio': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'website_url': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', }),
            'facebook_url': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'twitter_url': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'instagram_url': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'pinterest_url': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

**base.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'newsapp/css/style.css' %}">


    <title>
      {% block title %}
          Newsblog
      {% endblock %}
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">Newsblog</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">


      <!-- Category Menu Code -->
      {% if cat_menu %}
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Categories
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">


          {% for item in cat_menu %}
           <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'category' item|slugify %}">{{ item }}</a>
          {% endfor %}


        </div>
      </li>
      {% else %}

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'category-list' %}">Categories</a>
        </li>

      {% endif %}

      {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'add_post' %}">Add Post</a>
        </li>







      {% else %}
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
        </li>

      {% endif %}





    </ul>
{% if user.is_authenticated %}

    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            {{ user.first_name }}
            {{ user.last_name }}
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'edit_profile' %}">Edit Settings</a>

            {% if user.profile.id %}
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'edit_profile_page' user.profile.id %}">Edit Profile Page</a>

              <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'show_profile_page' user.profile.id %}">Show Profile Page</a>


            {% else %}
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'create_profile_page' %}">Create Profile Page</a>




            {% endif %}


          <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>



          </div>
      </li>



    </ul>

{% endif %}

  </div>
</nav>



    <br/>
    <div class="container">
      {% block content %}

      {% endblock %}
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are your bootstrap lines for CSS and JS, I mean CDN?

Comment: I dident put up all files but they are there, from the base.html file

Comment: i tried that and it dident help the form to look better. ANy bootstrap tips for my edit_profile_page?

Answer (score 0):

Here the problem is in the file forms.py .the Textarea,TextInput are included in
django.forms.widget
so ,

the code will be like this,

**forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm, PasswordChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms.widgets import TextInput, Textarea

from newsapp.models import Profile

class ProfilePageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('bio', 'profile_pic', 'website_url', 'facebook_url', 'twitter_url', 'instagram_url', 'pinterest_url')

        widgets = {
            'bio': Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'website_url': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', }),
            'facebook_url':TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'twitter_url': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'instagram_url':TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'pinterest_url': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

or

```
 widgets = {
                'bio': forms.widgets.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
..
..
..
..
.
.

}
```